# NoReverseMatch error . Reverse for '...' not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I was trying to implement dynamic urls in Django when this occured

In my template.py, I added this line

```
 <a href="{% url 'Index' %}" role="button">Go to Index</a>
```

My urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("moviez.urls"))
]
```

My moviez.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import IndexView

app_name = "moviez"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", IndexView, name="Index")
]
```

I think this should definitely should have work but it returned this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'Index' not found. 'Index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Can you please help me debug this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined an `app_name`, you need to add this as prefix separated by a colon (`:`), so:

```
<a href="{% url 'moviez:Index' %}" role="button">Go to Index</a>
```

For more information, see the [*URL namespaces and included URLconfs* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).